# How can I store Admin configuration in liferay

Tags: configuration, liferay, portlet

I wrote a portlet that have configuration page for admin settings.
How can I save this configurations and load them next time when admin click on configuration tab?

I have class that implements ConfigurationAction and I register it in portlet.xml.
I just don't know how to save these setting and load them whenever I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using portlet preferences to store and retrieve your settings.

To get your preferences you'll need to call:

```java
PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPreferences(
    long companyId, long ownerId, int ownerType, long plid,
    String portletId)
```

I would recommend using these parameters to make the preferences global to the portal instance:

```java
long companyId = themeDisplay.getCompanyId();
long ownerId = themeDisplay.getCompanyId();
int ownerType = PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_TYPE_COMPANY;
long plid = PortletKeys.PREFS_PLID_SHARED;
String portletId = "my_portlet_id";
```

Once you have your `portletPreferences` object, simply call the appropriate methods to get/store your keys as out lined by [the PortletPreference JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/javadoc/javax/portlet/PortletPreferences.html).